# Anyone experiencing Error 500 with Python GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app deployed on Google Appspot written in Python. It was working fine this afternoon, but right now at my current time (8:49PM PST), I'm experiencing:

```
POST http://s-t-h-c.appspot.com/dispatch 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

while making AJAX POST requests. I checked the server status on [System Status](https://code.google.com/status/appengine), and it says the issue was resolved a few hours ago. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Thanks for any insight!

~Carpetfizz

EDIT: The application still works fine on `localhost:8080`

Comment: What's in your log for that error.